# How to load string back xml with simpleXML in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, string

Would anyone know how i can "explode" a string back into "normal" xml format?
I found this script (ref:gooseflight,2010) that looks like it can do the job but the output comes out stuck together.

Here's the code:

```
 enter code herefunction combineXML($file)
{
    global $xmlstr;

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

    foreach($xml as $element)
        $xmlstr .= $element->asXML();
 }

$files[] = "tmp.xml";
$files[] = "traduction.xml";

$xmlstr = '<CAB>';  

foreach ($files as $file)
    combineXML($file);

$xmlstr .= '</CAB>';

// Convert string to XML for further processing

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
$bytes = file_put_contents("combined.xml", $xml->asXML())
```

Here is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CAB>
<CABO>XXXXXXXXXX0987650003</CABO><ACTIVITY>NONE</ACTIVITY><BEORI>blablaE</BEORI>BEDEST>blabla</BEDEST><NATRELA>more blabla</NATRELA><ANE>2014</ANE><NODEP>1111</NODEP>
</CAB>
```

So how could i seperate the nodes to look like this?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CAB>
<CABO>XXXXXXXXXX0987650003</CABO>
<ACTIVITY>NONE</ACTIVITY>
<BEORI>blablaE</BEORI>
<BEDEST>blabla</BEDEST>
<NATRELA>more blabla</NATRELA>
<ANE>2014</ANE>
<NODEP>1111</NODEP>
.....
</CAB>
```

Would anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use [DomDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class to save the XML; check this:

```
$dom_obj = new DOMDocument();
$dom_obj->loadXML($file);
// Do all your changes to the file by using DomDocument command (e.g. CreateElement, CreateAttribute, etc)
$dom_obj->formatOutput = true;
$dom_obj->save($file);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate. before I look into DOM, is there no way to accomplish that with the code above?

Comment: I am not sure if this work or not but try this `$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr)->asXML();`